# Razor Pages ASP.NET Core - OnPost() using datatables.net search bar returns no objects

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor, datatables

I have a page that is used to modify objects pulled from a database. When the page is loaded, a LINQ query creates a list of objects that is then displayed in an HTML table. A user can use a Drop Down Menu to select the changes they want to make, and then click the checkbox on the object they want this change to occur on. Everything works completely fine, until the datatables.net search bar comes into play.

Using this search bar, the number of items viewable on the list are refined, making it easier for the user to make the changes they need to make. Unfortunately, when the user clicks the button to make these changes, nothing happens. Looking at the OnPost(), no objects are returned there, so nothing could be updated.

Here is the back-end file for the page:

```
namespace CustomerPageTest.Pages.View
{
    public class EditClassificationTiersModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public int returnedClassification { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public int returnedTier { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public IEnumerable<vInfoView> vInfoViews { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public int assessmentID { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> ClassificationList { get; set; } = DatabaseClassificationData();

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public List<SelectListItem> TierList { get; set; }

        public void OnGet(int assessmentId)
        {
            assessmentID = assessmentId;
            TierList = DatabaseTierData();
            vInfoViews = GetvInfoViewsByAssessment(assessmentId);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            using (var context = new DataWarehouseContext())
            {
                foreach (var info in vInfoViews)
                {
                    if (info.isChecked)
                    {
                        var temp = context.RvtoolsVInfo
                            .Where(a => a.VmId.Equals(info.vmID))
                            .FirstOrDefault();

                        if(returnedClassification != 0) //If Data Classification form was changed we change it, else it stays the same
                            temp.DataClassificationId = returnedClassification;

                        if(returnedTier != 0) //If Tier form was changed we change it, else it stays the same
                            temp.TierNumber = returnedTier;

                        try
                        {
                            await context.SaveChangesAsync(); //Saves changes on selected objects
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToPage("/View/EditClassificationTiers", new { assessmentId = assessmentID });
        }
```

And this is the front-end file for the page:

```
@page "{assessmentId}"
@model CustomerPageTest.Pages.View.EditClassificationTiersModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "EditClassificationTiers";
}

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').dataTable({
                "paging": false,
                "search": {
                    "smart": false
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<h1 align="center" style="color:yellowgreen">Edit Classifications / Tiers</h1>
<br />

<form method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table" style="border: hidden !important; border-bottom: hidden !important; white-space: nowrap; width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3 class="text-light" style="white-space: nowrap">Data Classification:</h3>
                    <div class="form-group justify-content-center">
                        <select class="form-control" asp-for="returnedClassification" asp-items="Model.ClassificationList"></select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h3 class="text-light" style="white-space: nowrap">Tier:</h3>
                    <div class="form-group justify-content-center">
                        <select class="form-control" asp-for="returnedTier" asp-items="Model.TierList"></select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <br /><br /><br />
                    <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus text-light col-md-offset-6"></i>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add Classification / Tier" class="btn btn-dark text-light col-md-offset-6" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <br /><br /><br />
                    <div class="inline-right justify-content-center">
                        <a class="btn btn-dark" asp-page="/View/EditAssessment" asp-route-assessmentId="@Model.assessmentID">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i>    Back
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.assessmentID" name="assessmentID" />
    <table id="myTable" class="display cell-border stripe" role="grid" style="background-color: #dbdbdb; text-align:center; width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-dark">
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 5%;"></th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;"><strong>Name</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;"><strong>Datacenter</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 15%;"><strong>Cluster</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 15%;"><strong>Host</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;"><strong>Classification</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 10%;"><strong>Tier</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width: 25%"><strong>Annotation</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style="background-color: #dbdbdb;">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.vInfoViews.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr class="text-dark">
                    <td style="padding-top: 15px; width: 5%;">
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).isChecked" name="vInfoViews[@i].isChecked" />
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).vHostID" name="vInfoViews[@i].vHostID" />
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).assessmentID" name="vInfoViews[@i].assessmentID" />
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).vmID" name="vInfoViews[@i].vmID" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding-top: 15px; width: 10%;">
                        @Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).Name
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).Name" name="vInfoViews[@i].Name" />
                    </td>

                    <td style="padding-top: 15px; width: 10%;">
                        @Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).Datacenter
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).Datacenter" name="vInfoViews[@i].Datacenter" />
                    </td>

                    <td style="padding-top: 15px; width: 15%;">
                        @Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).Cluster
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).Cluster" name="vInfoViews[@i].Cluster" />
                    </td>

                    <td style="padding-top: 15px; width: 15%;">
                        @Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).hostName
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).hostName" name="vInfoViews[@i].hostName" />
                    </td>

                    <td style="padding-top: 15px; width: 10%;">
                        @Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).printClassification
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).classificationID" name="vInfoViews[@i].classificationID" />
                    </td>

                    <td style="padding-top: 15px; width: 10%;">
                        @Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).Tier
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).Tier" name="vInfoViews[@i].Tier" />
                    </td>

                    <td style="padding-top: 15px; width: 25%;">
                        @Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).Annotation
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.vInfoViews.ElementAt(i).Annotation" name="vInfoViews[@i].Annotation" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

I cannot give a working example, but I will provide screenshots of the current issue. These first screenshots is what happens when everything works fine:
[image: Selecting Row and Entering new information]

Next, this is what the OnPost() looks like:
[image]

You can see that the objects have passed through, so when the page is then reloaded, the changes are made:

[image]

Now let's say that I wish to use the search bar to change a row with Annotation: "PRTG Monitoring", like so:

[image]

When I look at the OnPost(), this is what I see

[image]

The list is empty!!

So, with this being an issue that I have no idea how to fix, and I cannot find solutions for it elsewhere, what do you guys think I should do? Is there a way that I could fill a new List object with the ID's that correspond to the objects in each row on the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar issue with .Net5. Here is my solution:

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddRazorPages(x => x.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/"))
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
                options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter(new DefaultNamingStrategy()));
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new UnixDateTimeConverter());
            })
```

Add FromBody for binded properties:

```
[BindProperty, FromBody]
    public DataTablesRequest DataTablesRequest { get; set; }
```

Post handler:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLoadAsync()
    {
```

Ajax call to fill datatable:

```
table = $('#studentsGrid').dataTable({
            processing: true, // for show progress bar
            serverSide: true, // for process server side
            filter: true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            ordering: true,
            orderMulti: false, // for disable multiple column at once
            pageLength: 5,
            paging: true,
            responsive: true,
            searching: true,
            cache: false,
            ajax: {
                url: "@Url.Page("/Students")?handler=Load",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                data: function (d) { console.log(d); return  JSON.stringify(d);},
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "FullName", "name": "FullName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Phone", "name": "Phone", "autoWidth": true }
            ]
```